# Prove that for every $n\geq 2$ there exists an n-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Any help would be appreciated: Prove that for every $n\geq 2$ there exists an n-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees.

Comment: I recommend you start by trying to prove it for $n=2$. (You might then change your plan.)

Comment: what happens when $n=2$? can you find a graph such that $E(u)\neq E(v)$?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil wow you beat me to the punch

Comment: What are all these different degrees? You might need to invest in some pigeonholes.

Comment: Perhaps change "there exists" to "there does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

The claim as currently written "*for every $n\geq 2$ there exists an $n$-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees*" is false and can be seen to be false by way of counter example.  We can very quickly and easily describe every graph on two vertices up to isomorphism.

`*   *`   and `*----*`

The degree sequence of the first is (0,0) and of the second is (1,1), neither of which satisfy the claim.

---

A more interesting and challenging question, and very likely the intended question that you should be trying to prove is that it is in fact **never** possible to find such a graph for any $n$.  That is:

> For every simple graph on $n\geq 2$ vertices there must be at least two vertices in the graph with the same degree.

To approach note the following things:

- Ignoring everything else about the graph but the number of vertices $n$, looking at an individual vertex, what are the possible values for its degree?

> $0,1,2,\dots,n-1$, so there are $n$ options.

- If there is an isolated vertex in the graph, are there any of those aforementioned degrees which are now impossible?  How many degrees are possible taking that into account then?

> Can there be a vertex of degree zero and a vertex of degree $n-1$ in the same graph with $n$ vertices?  The degree zero vertex is next to no other vertex but the degree $n-1$ vertex is next to every other vertex including the degree zero one...

- If there is not an isolated vertex in the graph, are there any of those aforementioned degrees which are now impossible?  How many degrees are possible taking that into account then?

> If there are no isolated vertices, there are no vertices of degree zero...

Use these observations in conjunction with the pigeonhole principle to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Nicely laid out. I was thinking "why does it work for $n=1$" could be neatly expressed by: "connecting to every other vertex and connecting to no other vertex are the same thing".

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, consider a simple graph with $5$ vertices. The maximum degree in such a graph would be $4$, if a vertex were connected to every other vertex. The minimum degree would be $0$, for a vertex that is not connected to any other (an isolated vertex). So we consider the range $[0,4]$ and indeed there are $5$ distinct integers. However notice that the minimum and maximum values calculated cannot exist in the same graph - there cannot be both a vertex connected to all the others and also a vertex connected to none of the others. So the maximum number of distinct degree values is not more than $4$ and so - by the ever-helpful pigeonhole principle - at least two of the $5$ vertices must have the same degree.

It is not hard to see how this applies to a graph with any number of vertices (I leave it to you to do so). There must always be two vertices with the same degree in a simple graph.